# How can I read the TIFFTAG_DATETIME using GDAL in Python

Tags: gdal

I am currently using GDAL from Python to read and transform coordinates and that works well. I would now like to be able to read some of the none geographic tags, for example, TIFFTAG_DATETIME using GDAL. I have searched the net but have been unable to find any examples. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the GDAL library from OSGEO here:
http://www.osgeo.org/ , there are also nice Windows binaries located at [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1500-gdal-2-1-0-mapserver-7-0-1.zip) thanks to Tamas Szekeres. Just make sure you install the right version for the version of Python your running.

In your Python code you can import the library like so:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

Then in your code body, you can get a reference to you raster, say, by iterating over a folder of tif's like below...

```
...
for raster in glob.glob(rootdir + "*.tif"):
...
```

Then invoke GDAL to open the raster and get a 'handle' to the data source like:

```
ds = gdal.Open(raster, 0)
```

Use "GetMetadataItem" method to pick out the metadata item you're interested in like so:

```
print ds.GetMetadataItem("TIFFTAG_DATETIME")
```

You can review other metadata tags here: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html

Close the raster dataset

```
ds = None
```

Comment: Can you provide some context/guidance for the code that you have supplied as an answer, please?  Code only answers tend to attract flags and downvotes.